# Pine script - Enter position when multiple conditions are true or false

Tags: pine-script

Sorry I am new to pine script. Hope you can help me on this. I am trying to add multiple conditions in to my exiting V4 script as follows.

```
Condition1 = crossover(close,ema1)
Condition2 = crossunder(close,ema1)
Condition3 = crossover(rsi,50)
Condition4 = crossunder(rsi,50)
How do I make the conditions status "True" or "False" for the followings scenario?
Long = (if last cross was Condition1) and Condition3
Short = (if last cross was Condition2) and Condition4
```

Many Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Exactly as you have written in natural language.

```
Long = Condition1 and Condition3
```

And later you can trigger an alert when `Long` is true.

This has nothing to do with Pine, this is Boolean algebra which you should read about to understand it better: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Boolean_algebra